# What is the true meaning of the shlok Dharmo Rakshati Rakshitah?

Tags: dharma, shloka

Dharma Rakshati Rakshitah means if you protect Dharma, then Dharma will protect you.
Can someone understand me better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a part of a verse from the Manu Smriti.

> Dharmo eva hato hanti **dharmo rakshati rakshitaha** |
>  TasmAd dharmo na
>   hantavyo mA no dharmo hato vadhita ||
>
> 8.15. ’Justice, being violated, destroys; **justice, being preserved, preserves:** therefore justice must not be violated, lest violated
>   justice destroy us.

[Commentary on this verse](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200908.html) by MedhAtithi is as follows:

> Judgment should not be perverted, through fear; because justice, when
>   violated, ‘blights’— our prosperity, as also the prosperity of the
>   sinful party and his helpers.
>
> Similarly, when ‘preserved,’ justice removes dangers from all sources;
>   so that even though angered, the party (defeated) cannot do any harm.
>
> ‘Hence’—i.e., knowing this, that happiness and unhappiness are based
>   upon morality, one should not violate morality (or justice). If we
>   violate justice, justice shall, like an enraged serpent, strike back
>   at us; so lest justice blight us—i.e., with a view to saving
>   ourselves,—we should preserve justice.—(15)